# Как определить, что окно закрыто скриптом?

Tags: javascript, window.open

Задача: на странице A открывать окно в браузере с url B, выполнить код в окне B и автоматически закрыть окно, когда скрипт выполнен. Если окно B закрыто автоматически, выполнить скрипт на странице A. Если окно B было закрыто пользователем до выполнения скрипта в окне B - не делать ничего.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // ... скрипт в окне B
 window.parent.MyFunction();
```